# Is it possible to add security section in web.config to external file

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web.config-transform

I need block a huge IP list via config file

```
<security>
      <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="true">
        <clear />          
        <add ipAddress="1.0.1.0" subnetMask="255.255.255.0" />
        <add ipAddress="1.0.2.0" subnetMask="255.255.254.0" />
        <add ipAddress="1.0.8.0" subnetMask="255.255.248.0" />
        <add ipAddress="1.0.32.0" subnetMask="255.255.224.0" />
        ...
      </ipSecurity>
</security>
```

Is it possible to add security section in web.config to external file ?

Comment: Yes you can, google `configSource`.

Comment: @tweray Yes but it dos't work for security section

Answer (score 7, accepted):

c:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config

change the configuration for the web server:

from:

```
< section name="ipSecurity" overrideModeDefault="Deny" / >
```

to:

```
< section name="ipSecurity" overrideModeDefault="Allow" / >
```

and your web.config

```
< configuration > 
< system.webServer > 
< security > 
< ipSecurity configSource="fileWithIps.config" / > 
< /security > 
< /system.webServer > 
< /configuration >
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you could achieve this, but for a start I would look at the ConfigurationManager's [ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms134269%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method for mapping a secondary config file