# Adding Ip security for many locations

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, web-config

How to add multiple rules for multiple locations

I have an MVC application I added the following section in Web.Config:

```
  <system.webServer>
     <security>
       <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false">
          <clear /> 

       <add ipAddress="127.0.0.1" allowed="true" />

       <add ipAddress="41.111.32.153" allowed="true" />
       </ipSecurity>
    </security>
  <system.webServer>
```

now I want to add another security rule to allow access just the home page for some ips, what I've tried is adding this section under the base one like :

```
<location path="Home">
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false">
        <clear /> 
        <add ipAddress="44.244.6.162" allowed="true" />
        <add ipAddress="44.244.6.163" allowed="true" />
      </ipSecurity>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</location>
```

I tried also `<location path="Home" allowOverride="true">` but it doesn't work as well!.

Could you please tell me what should I write to work with me ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26804752/is-it-possible-to-add-security-section-in-web-config-to-external-file)

Answer (score 0):

Why you cannot use an Authorization Filter? With this method you can add ip configuration at runtime, maybe with a SQL table, and perform authorization in every action.