# IP Security - how to configure web.config with file that contain IP addresses

Tags: web-services, web-config

I have many web services and in each web.config of these web services, I have configured security to allow IP addresses to access the service.

My question is: how can I set all my web.config with a way that will contain the list of IP addresses to allow? the idea is that in case of change of IP, I modify the file only and not all web.config.

thank you very much

Comment: It's a little tricky to help you with the information provided here, but typically you use the concepts of allowed audiences to manage what ip addresses or hosts are permitted access to your services. If you deploy services in controlled fashion (I suggest looking at Octopus Deploy) then you would set up an agreed set of addresses in the deployment tool rather than within your code/source control to avoid security flaws.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `configSource` property on the ipSecurity section.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26809462/1192506